# Read ecw file with gdal in python?

Tags: python, windows, gdal

I installed gdal from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal on Windows 10.
I added the 
`PATH=C:\Users\workspace\gdal\bin`, 
`GDAL_DATA=C:\Users\workspace\gdal\bin\gdal-data` and `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=C:\Users\workspace\gdal\bin\plugins` 
to my system & user variables (Here I'm not sure these are right). 
Lastly installed gdal with pip in python 3.6

I am trying to read a file like this:

```
ecw_path = r'files\area1.ecw'

ecw_file = gdal.Open(ecw_path)
```

The result is
`` ERROR 4: `files\area1.ecw' not recognized as a supported file format. ``

So, I couldn't find a working way to read an ecw file in python